# Javascript auto page refresh code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this is the code that comes in head section and it will automatically refresh the whole page in 1 min as i put 6000 in the code below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout('window.location.href=window.location.href;', 6000);
</script>
```

is there any way for example, when there's 10 seconds left to refresh the page then, a button will display and say "Click here to reset timer" and it will reset that timer to 1 min again?

Comment: Use window.setInterval() instead

Comment: can you please be more clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <script language="javascript">
        var timeout,interval
         var threshold = 15000;
        var secondsleft=threshold;
        startschedule();

        window.onload = function()
        {
            startschedule();
        }

         function startChecking()
         {
            secondsleft-=1000;
            if(secondsleft <= 10000)
            {
                document.getElementById("clickme").style.display="";
                document.getElementById("timercounter").innerHTML = Math.abs((secondsleft/1000))+" secs";  
            }
        }
        function startschedule()
        {
              clearInterval(timeout);
              clearInterval(interval);
              timeout = setTimeout('window.location.href=window.location.href;', threshold);
              secondsleft=threshold;
               interval = setInterval(function()
               {
                   startChecking();
               },1000)              
            }

            function resetTimer()
            {
            startschedule();
            document.getElementById("clickme").style.display="none";
            document.getElementById("timercounter").innerHTML="";
             }
    </script>
            Please wait...<span id="timercounter"></span>
            <button id="clickme" style="display:none;" onclick="javascript:resetTimer();">Click here to reset timer</button>
```

Comment: this 2 words "Thank You" is not really enough to say. i been looking for this since long time now you only solved my problem. thank you so much sir.

Comment: and there's 1 more small thing if you can help me about it. it's almost the same way, now here when 10 seconds left , it will display the button to reset timer. is there any way to make like for example, when 10 seconds left, that last 10 seconds much be showing as countdown text like, 10, 9, 8, etc on the page. and when it's 0 then the page must refresh. i need all that in this same code you give me. thanks again

Comment: i don't know how to message you my friend. can you please check my question at this link and if it's possible to answer me please
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28261727/javascript-hide-div-and-show-another-div-with-simple-countdown

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the following html for the button:

```
<button id="cancel-reload-button" style="display: none" onclick="cancelReload()">Cancel Reload</button>
```

And this as the script (Note: this gives the idea, but is not neccesarily fully tested):

```
// Variable for holding the reference to the current timeout
var myTimeout;

// Starts the reload, called when the page is loaded.
function startReload() {
   myTimeout = setTimeout(function() {

       document.getElementByID("cancel-reload-button").style.display = "inline";

       myTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
           window.location.reload();
       } 10000)

   }, 50000);
}

// Cancel the reload and start it over. Called when the button is
// clicked.
function cancelReload() {
    clearTimeout(myTimeout)
    startReload()
}

// On page load call this function top begin.
startReload();
```

I created two functions, one for starting the reload and the second one for cancelling it.

Then I assigned the timeout to the variable `myTimeout` which can be used to later cancel the timeout.

Then I called myTimeout twice - Once for 50 secs, at which point it shows the button and once for 10 secs after which it finally reloads.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `style=display: none` instead of `hidden`?

Answer (score 0):

How about below? If you click on OK to reset timer, it would keep giving the confirm box every 50 seconds. If you click cancel, it will refresh the page in 10 seconds.

```js
setInterval(function(){ var r = confirm("Reset Timer");
if (r == true) {
 setTimeout('window.location.href=window.location.href;', 60000);
} else {
   setTimeout('window.location.href=window.location.href;', 10000);
}
}, 50000);
```

**Note:** In your question you specified 1 minute, but your code works for 6 seconds(6000 -- > 6 seconds not 60 seconds) I have included for a minute

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it is make a function with a timeout, and invoke that function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var refreshFunc = function(){
      setTimeout(function(){
                     var r = confirm("Do you want to reset the timer?");
                     if(r === false){
                       window.location.href=window.location.href;
                     }else{
                       refreshFunc();
                     }
                  }, 6000);
    };
    refreshFunc();
</script>
```

One big problem with using confirm in this case is you cannot program it to reject.  You would have to implement you own modal/dialog box so you can auto reject in 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `setInterval()`:

```js
var time;

$(function() {
  time = $('#time');
  $('#reset').on('click', reset);
  start();
});

var timer, left;

var start = function() {
  left = +(time.text()); //parsing 
  timer = setInterval(function() {
    if (0 <= left) {
      time.text(left--);
    } else {
      clearInterval(timer);
      location.replace(location);
    }
  }, 1000);
};

var reset = function() {
  if (timer) {
    clearInterval(timer);
  }
  time.text('59');
  start();
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1><span id='time'>59</span> second(s) left</h1>
<input id='reset' value='Reset' type='button' />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 setTimeout calls, one to make the "Reset" button show up and another one for the refresh timer reset. The trick is to store the second setTimeout on a global variable and use clearTimeout to reset it if the button is pressed.
Here is some JavaScript code to illustrate:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var autoRefreshTime = 30 * 1000; // 60000ms = 60secs = 1 min
var warningTime = autoRefreshTime - (10 * 1000); // 10 secs before autoRefreshTime

waitTimeout = setTimeout('window.location.href=window.location.href;', autoRefreshTime);
warningTimeout = setTimeout('ShowResetButton();', warningTime);

function ShowResetButton() {
    // Code to make the "Reset" button show up
}

// Make this function your button's onClick handler
function ResetAutoRefreshTimer() {
    clearTimeout(waitTimeout);
    waitTimeout = setTimeout('window.location.href=window.location.href;', autoRefreshTime);
}
</script>
```