# Javascript hide div and show another div with simple countdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

is there any way to hide div show another div using javascript?

```
<div class="div1">"here must show countdown 10 seconds"</div>
<div class="div2">"show this div after countdown"</div>
```

for example: when page loaded, div1 must display and it must have 10 seconds countdown. when countdown is done then hide div1 and show div2

Thanks for who answer my question.

and Thanks for RTPMatt answered me once but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this

```
    <script language="javascript">
    var timeout,interval
    var threshold = 10000;
    var secondsleft=threshold;

    window.onload = function()
    {
        startschedule();
    }

     function startChecking()
     {
        secondsleft-=1000;
        document.querySelector(".div1").innerHTML = "Activating in " + Math.abs((secondsleft/1000))+" secs";  
        if(secondsleft == 0)
        {
            //document.getElementById("clickme").style.display="";
            clearInterval(interval);
            document.querySelector(".div1").style.display="none";
            document.querySelector(".div2").style.display="";
        }
    }
    function startschedule()
    {
          clearInterval(interval);
          secondsleft=threshold;
          document.querySelector(".div1").innerHTML = "Activating in " + Math.abs((secondsleft/1000))+" secs";  
           interval = setInterval(function()
           {
               startChecking();
           },1000)              
   }

   function resetTimer()
   {
        startschedule();
   }
</script>
    <div class="div1">"here must show countdown 10 seconds"</div>
    <div class="div2" style="display:none;">"show this div after countdown"</div>
```

Comment: i wish you the best luck in the world. the code above worked perfectly. thank you so much .

Comment: hey. i have tried that code above on youtube iframe here's link how i did 
http://plnkr.co/edit/1JNleQc6JhvplHEfZqvW?p=preview

video will load at same time with countdown is counting . and it will play like in background while countdown is counting. is there any way to make it load that iframe after countdown is over? it must load iframe and play it after countdown is 0

Comment: Place the desired url in src attribute of the iframe when you are showing it, hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your time answering me i really appreciate it. all your codes worked perfectly for me but i am stuck only here in last step.

check this first link it will work if i switch videos by clicking video 1 and video 2 but when i add your codes it will not work switching videos
http://plnkr.co/edit/RhMjODNrZggtY0tEsCif?p=preview


and here's with your code that will prevent switching videos don't know what's wrong
http://plnkr.co/edit/Duqck5WVVKzYA43hJN9z?p=preview

Comment: Try updating the jquery path http://tgo-tv.com/js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js is not working. Use https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js

Comment: did you try clicking video 1 and video 2 ? on first link it's working fine. using that js file and without your code. but in second link i also used same js file but with your code to hide div and show another then switching doesn't work

Comment: Sorry to be quick to respond before, please take a look at the updated fork http://plnkr.co/edit/pPzFf6DEFf35omwgmW8C?p=preview, hope this answers your query

Comment: Thank you very much my friend. i will never forget all this help. it worked perfectly

Comment: i am sure you are more than teacher in javascript programming :)

Comment: hey my friend. just 1 thing i wanted to ask, how do i put all my javascript codes in one file instead of making many .js file for each thing i want to create and without getting problem in other elements? like in css we can make style by opening and closing like this div1{here style} but how we do it for all javascript codes in one file?

Comment: You can copy all your existing code in single js file. You can put a comment line like //******************** between sections to De-markate sections of your js. However, you have be careful to ensure that only function declarations exist and if you want to put handlers on DOM like $(document).ready(...), ensure that the DOM elements coming under handler exists in page. Also, you can go a step further to reduce the download overhead and compress the js by creating a minified copy of the same, you can tools on the web like http://jscompress.com/ for this purpose.

Comment: thanks a lot. can you please check this http://plnkr.co/edit/mOF2lTSoGRqp9uoBBApf?p=preview

will you see please if you can make , i want it when page loaded then that id from data-str="p9zdCra9gCE" this id must get in this area i wrote "[GET THAT ID HERE]" and also wen each button clicked, its id from data-str must go into that area i pointed. hope you understand what i mean

Comment: Please look at the updated fork, http://plnkr.co/edit/tqyKrOrubkSGncF2ALv3?p=preview hope it helps!

Comment: sir, if you can please check my question and answer it, it's almost same as this question you answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30924340/adding-file-name-using-javascript

Comment: I have posted my answer, please take a look and let me know if it helped!

Comment: thank you sir but i found a way for that using php and it's fine. the only thing i need for now i didn't find out is that, is it possible to create search using php or javascript without database? for example i have search form on index.php and when i write something and click search and it will bring me my pages in search.php

Comment: here's my question page sir http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30990855/create-search-box-for-website-using-php-and-javascript-without-database

Comment: sir. you didn't answer on my question page

Comment: sorry for the delay, i have looked into the question. Can you please explain in detail what you are trying to achieve in your query so that i can get a idea!

Comment: what i am trying to make is simple search for website that i can search for my pages with it. for example if some one visit my site and he want to go to page "Phones" and he will type "Phones" in search box and click enter. and it will bring for him pages that is with keyword "Phones" that he typed. hope you understand

Comment: Proposing a simple solution, http://plnkr.co/edit/ALCKf1ZlNfypgPzzcQCj?p=preview. Enter Phones and if Phones.html exists in your directory, the ajax callback will navigate to it. Hope it helps

Comment: Enter Phones in the text input and click go and if all goes well you should see test in http://plnkr.co/edit/ALCKf1ZlNfypgPzzcQCj?p=preview

Comment: oh no sir. what you did for me is like navigator. look at this i explained using paint, http://s21.postimg.org/jlddia1pz/examplesearch.png hope you understand from this

Comment: or look at this example some websites using http://www.boostmobile.com/search/?q=phones

Comment: you will have to create a database for that. Then you can perform a search on the same using SQL

Comment: Hemant dear can you please check my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42975422/play-the-video-instantly-instead-of-click-to-play-using-javascript

Answer (score 2):

You might try this :

```
$(function (){
 $("#div1").show();
 setTimeout(function(){$("#div1").hide(); $("#div2").show();},10*1000)
})
```

When dom is loaded , you show `div1`. then you start a timer which when pulse , hides `div1` and show `div2`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but Hemant is code worked for me. appreciate your time