# Automatically adding links to files in a folder in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If it's possible, can some one please help me with this. I made YouTube for example. As you see in this PLNKR LINK: http://plnkr.co/edit/44EQKSjP3Gl566wczKL6?p=preview

For example `embed` is my folder and in that folder I have files named `p9zdCra9gCE` and `QrMOu4GU3uU`, as you see them in here:

```
<div class="ytid" data-str="p9zdCra9gCE">video 1</div>
<div class="ytid" data-str="QrMOu4GU3uU">video 2</div>
```

If it's possible I want it so that whenever I add a file like, `p9zdCra9gCE.html` or `QrMOu4GU3uU.html` in the `embed` folder it will be automatically added on the index page next to other video buttons to become like this:

```
<div class="ytid" data-str="p9zdCra9gCE">video 1</div>
<div class="ytid" data-str="QrMOu4GU3uU">video 2</div>
<div class="ytid" data-str="AnotherFile">video 3</div>
<div class="ytid" data-str="AnotherFile">video 4</div>
<div class="ytid" data-str="AnotherFile">video 5</div>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please post your code in the question and not as a link.

Comment: i didn't try anything yet i was wondering if it's possible
and i posted my code in that link it makes it easier for some one that can help

Comment: Consider adding a server side language tag like nodejs or php. All of the tags in this question refer to client side tech that cannot access the file system

Comment: hmm, so how do i do that can you help me with it even a little ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/264659524/Files/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/264659524/Files/myjs.js"></script>
<style>
.ytid{float:left;margin-right:5px;border:1px solid black}
.clear{clear:both;}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="listids">
    <div class="ytid" data-str="p9zdCra9gCE">video 1</div>
    <div class="ytid" data-str="QrMOu4GU3uU">video 2</div>
 </div>


 <div class="clear"></div>
<br>

<div class="vidarea">
            <div class="load_vid"></div>
        <iframe class="vid_src" data-src="" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" style="width:640px; height:460px;display:none;" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
            </div>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<textarea class="embed" data-content="&lt;iframe scrolling=&quot;no&quot; frameborder=&quot;0&quot; marginheight=&quot;0&quot; marginwidth=&quot;0&quot; allowtransparency=&quot;true&quot; width:640px; height:460px;&quot; allowfullscreen=&quot;&quot; src=&quot;https://www.youtube.com/embed/[ytvidID]&quot;&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;" onfocus="this.select();" onclick="this.select()">
    &lt;iframe scrolling=&quot;no&quot; frameborder=&quot;0&quot; marginheight=&quot;0&quot; marginwidth=&quot;0&quot; allowtransparency=&quot;true&quot; width:640px; height:460px;&quot; allowfullscreen=&quot;&quot; src=&quot;https://www.youtube.com/embed/[ytvidID]&quot;&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;

</textarea>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $(".vid_src").attr("data-src", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/p9zdCra9gCE");
        var t = "1";
        var n = $(".embed").attr("data-content");
        n = n.replace("[ytvidID]", t);
        $(".embed").html(n);
        $(".listids").slideDown();

        bindEventHandlers();


        $(".embed").keyup(function()
        {
            var valuetoinspect = $(this).val();
            if(valuetoinspect.indexOf(".html") != -1)
            {
                var vidvalue = valuetoinspect.split(".html");
                checkAndMergeVideoListing(vidvalue[0]);
            }
        })
    })

    function checkAndMergeVideoListing(video)
    {
        var count = $(".ytid").length;

        if( $(".ytid[data-str=\""+video+"\"]").attr("data-str") == null)
        {
            var $div = $("<div></div>");
            $div.addClass("ytid");
            $div.attr("data-str",video);
            $div.html("video " + (count+1));

            $(".listids").append($div);

            bindEventHandlers();

            $(".ytid[data-str=\""+video+"\"]").click();
        }
    }

    function bindEventHandlers()
    {
        $(".ytid").unbind("click").click(function(e) {
            var t = $(this).attr("data-str");
            var n = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + t + "";
            var r = $(".embed").attr("data-content");
            r = r.replace("[ytvidID]", t);
            $(".embed").html(r);
            $(".vid_src").attr("src", n);
            clearInterval(interval);
            document.querySelector(".load_vid").style.display = "none";
            $(".vid_src").show();
            return
        })
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Please check [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/YABteh37vTkJx0UIWbxy?p=preview) for demo, assuming in the embed textarea you enter something like p9zdCra9gCE.html. It gets added in the video tab [the same starts playing]. Please let me know if i was not able to grasp your requirement. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

To help you on your way "a little" I would suggest this:
1. Use php or another SERVER SIDE language. As mentioned in the comments you will not be able to acces the file system on the server with javascript or jquery.
2. Use for example the scandir() method (thats php) to get the contents of your folder. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php
3. This will return an array of files and folders in the scanned directory. Use a foreach loop to generate the ytid divs.

If you have no idea what this means I suggest following a tutorial on php on codecademy or another online resource. Good luck!

Comment: i didn't expect this kind of answer. i need some one who can help me for like, some codes "how" "example" etc but thanks for your time answering to my question

Comment: i will keep this question open, i am still expecting a person who helped me a lot in past. i am waiting for him...

Comment: I get where you are coming from but your question shows no research effort at all. What did you try? What did you find out? Why is your solution not working? Better to learn how to fish than try to get one for free :)

Comment: well i have tried this in youtube and it seems to work but i want some how to put file name in  here <div class="ytid" data-str="p9zdCra9gCE">video 1</div> replace it with "p9zdCra9gCE" and remove file extension to become "p9zdCra9gCE" instead of "p9zdCra9gCE.html" here's video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V3UazvF-zF4